# How can I create a dropdown combobox from a list in a Python FMX GUI App?

Tags: python, arrays, user-interface, combobox, firemonkey

I'm creating a GUI using [DelphiFMX GUI library for Python](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python) that has a `ComboBox` on it and I also have a list (array) of strings that I want to put into the ComboBox. Here's my current code:

```
from delphifmx import *

class frmMain(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Caption = 'My Form with ComboBox'
        self.Width = 600
        self.Height = 250

        self.myComboBox = ComboBox(self)
        self.myComboBox.Parent = self
        self.myComboBox.Align = "Top"
        self.myComboBox.Margins.Top = 20
        self.myComboBox.Margins.Right = 20
        self.myComboBox.Margins.Bottom = 20
        self.myComboBox.Margins.Left = 20

        Months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

def main():
    Application.Initialize()
    Application.Title = "My Application"
    Application.MainForm = frmMain(Application)
    Application.MainForm.Show()
    Application.Run()
    Application.MainForm.Destroy()

main()
```

I've tried doing things like:

1. `self.myComboBox.Items.AddStrings(Months)`, but then I get a `TypeError: "AddStrings" called with invalid arguments. Error: Could not find a method with compatible arguments` error.
2. `self.myComboBox.Items.Text(Months)`, but then I get a `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` error.
3. `self.myComboBox.Text = Months`, but then I get an `AttributeError: Error in setting property Text` error.

How can I get the `Months` array into the ComboBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
for i in range(0, len(Months)):
    self.myComboBox.Items.Add(Months[i])
```

[image: Python GUI with ComboBox]

So the full code is:

```
from delphifmx import *

class frmMain(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Caption = 'My Form with ComboBox'
        self.Width = 600
        self.Height = 250

        self.myComboBox = ComboBox(self)
        self.myComboBox.Parent = self
        self.myComboBox.Align = "Top"
        self.myComboBox.Margins.Top = 20
        self.myComboBox.Margins.Right = 20
        self.myComboBox.Margins.Bottom = 20
        self.myComboBox.Margins.Left = 20

        Months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

        for i in range(0, len(Months)):
            self.myComboBox.Items.Add(Months[i])

def main():
    Application.Initialize()
    Application.Title = "My Application"
    Application.MainForm = frmMain(Application)
    Application.MainForm.Show()
    Application.Run()
    Application.MainForm.Destroy()

main()
```